# Readability test program with Coleman-Liau index using C

Tags: c, cs50

**i don't understand why my code is not calculating the Coleman-Liau index right. its not giving me the correct calculation. I need help please.
this code should print
Grade 8, when this text is typed "When he was nearly thirteen, my brother Jem got his arm badly broken at the elbow. When it healed, and Jem's fears of never being able to play football were assuaged, he was seldom self-conscious about his injury. His left arm was somewhat shorter than his right; when he stood or walked, the back of his hand was at right angles to his body, his thumb parallel to his thigh."

Grade 9, when this text is typed "There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy."
but its not**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//functions declarations
void count_letters(char * msg);
void count_words(char * msg);
void count_sentence(char * msg);


// number of letters, words and sentence
float no_letters = 0;
float no_words = 0;
float no_sentence = 0;

//variables in Coleman-Liau index
float l;
float s;
float index;


int main (void)
{
    char * text = get_string("Text: \n");
    count_letters(text);
    count_words(text);
    count_sentence(text);
    
    //calculation of l
    l = no_letters / no_words * 100;
    //calculation of s
    s = no_sentence / no_words * 100;
    //index calculation
    index = 0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8;
    int grade = round(index);
    printf("%i\n", grade);
    
    //grading
    if(grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if(grade >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
    
}

//function to count letters
void count_letters(char * msg)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++)
    {
        if(msg[i] != ' ')
        {
            no_letters++;
        }
    }

}

//function to count words
void count_words(char * msg)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++)
    {
        if(msg[i] == ' ' || msg[i] == '\0')
        {
            no_words++;
        }
    }
}

//function to count sentence
void count_sentence(char * msg)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++)
   {
       if (msg[i] == '.' || msg[i] == '?' || msg[i] == '!' || msg[i] == '"' || msg[i] == ':')
       {
           no_sentence++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it counting the letters, words and sentences correctly? What is wrong, apart from "wrong answer".

Comment: its counts the letters, words and sentences correctly.
the only thing wrong is the calculation of the index and maybe l and s

Comment: Have you done any debugging? That is, trace the execution of your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: yes i used printf to debug. i still didnt get the bug. but i didnt use the debugger

Comment: Try dialling in the numbers (5 sentences, 119 words, and 639 letters) given in the example in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Liau_index), just before doing the calculations.

Comment: instead of 14.5, i am getting 13.6

Answer (score 0):

Does it count the words correctly? It looks like you know that "This is a sentence." has 4 words, but only 3 spaces. The `count_words` function, however, doesn't see it that way. It will count only 3 words. It is not going to count the terminating `\0` because of this `i < strlen(msg)`.

Comment: yeah thanks. this was helpful. but that was not the only bug. the letters counter was also counting punctuation marks.